# Resampling methodology when projecting a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, srtm

When projecting an SRTM raster with "Project Raster" tool in ArcGIS10.2, what is the best resampling methodology, bilinear ot cubic convolution?

Comment: I'd go bilinear. Cubic tends to be a little over-enthusiastic where values change significantly over a short distance and nearest is intended for discreet data.